# What is the cheapest / most efficient device to *read* a Blu-ray (movie *or* data) disc on a desktop?

Tags: blu-ray

Can I hook say a [Samsung BD-P4600](http://reviews.cnet.com/blu-ray-players/samsung-bd-p4600/4505-9991_7-33488071.html) to my computer & read even data discs on the computer? or is a Blu-ray player different from a Blu-ray drive?

As guidelines prohibit asking for a shopping recommendation, merely a Blu-ray player versus a Blu-ray drive versus any other devices' general price efficiencies' differences would be ok.

Comment: We also take software "shopping" questions as off topic. Read [here for more info](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). If you have any specific complaints please go to [meta]. Rollbacks and edit messages are not visible to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Blu-ray player is definitely different from a computer Blu-ray drive. The Blu-ray player (or for that matter any Optical Disc player) is essentially designed for reading predefined patterns of content off an optical media. In this case, only video.

The software to make sense of whatever is read is actually a firmware ("kind of" permanent software specifically made for a purpose and hardware configuration).

A computer disc drive (BD/DVD/CD) on the other hand just reads the data in chunks, does [error correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_Control_Coding) as needed. It's up to the software and/or hardware on the PC to derive meaning out of the content being read.

So essentially you'd need a BD ROM (cheapest PC mechanism) to read a Blu-ray disc.

[image]

The cheapest one I could find on amazon is an [LG UH12LS series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004U65FM8) BD ROM/DVD Writer

Comment: thanks, what I was wondering. would it be possible to buy a cheap blu-ray player & (**easily-enough**) change the firmware?

Comment: No, it won't be possible.

Comment: A Blu-ray player contains such a drive … so in theory, yes, but in practice, most probably not. A standard computer drive might be cheaper after all. @joe